# How can i hash locations of my objects in a list even if adding/removing items

Tags: c#, dictionary, time-complexity

I have a list and a dictionary combination where by my dictionary holds a int value which is essentially the position in the list. Like this:

```
Dictionary = new Dictionary<Vector3, int>();
List = new List<Node>();

//getting an item from the list by position
return List[Dictionary[myPosition]];
```

The problem is i am adding/removing from the list and so the index position of items is changing, this in rare occasions leads to 2 items with the same index position since its overly complicated to update the whole dictionary to reduce every item's index by 1 if i remove an item for example.

So i need some other for my dictionary to link to the Node so my look ups are **O(1)**.

What options do i have at this point to achieve this? I am trying to avoid **O(n)** using a for loop to find the item by position, that's the last case scenario that i am trying to avoid.

So what can i do about this issue?

Comment: That user that edited has been purposely making senseless edits to gain rep.

Comment: Add/remove to list already O(n)... so updating dictionary will not make it any worse... Are you sure you understand where time is spent?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i know adding/removing it but i might aswell make look ups O(1) if i can.

Comment: Could you explain why do you need to retrieve an index in the list?

Comment: The list retrieves the node not the index.

Comment: @Sir I'm confused where do you have a problem than - update both dictionary and list on add/remove and you still have your O(1) lookup working correctly... Which operation you trying to make faster (clearly neither add/remove as you are using list, nor lookup which is already O(1))

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if i remove an item from the list, the index position of every item in the dictionary is off by 1. So i would have to iterate my dictionary for every Vector3 position by finding the index in the list as i iterate the dictionary. Looping a dictioanry is slow to start with, and then i have O(n) for every item in the list to find its index to merely update the dictionary values by -1. Thats going to hurt with large items.

Comment: How decrementing value based on condition (`index = index < indexRemoved ? index : index -1`) is more than O(n) in your case I don't know... But good that you did not really need to have your node elements ordered and got solution for your problem (Note that you may want to clarify question as it was unclear from the question that order is not important - it is somewhat strange to start with List in such case).

Comment: Its O(n) because every index in the dictionary has to be updated. But the answer solved that problem i just wasn't linking my data in a smart way :)

Comment: Extra side note: make sure your `Vector3` has sensible comparison - hopefully it is integer type vector and not float... or you make no computations on your vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just have your dictionary map directly to the value you're seeking?:

```
Dictionary = new Dictionary<Vector3, Node>();
```

No indices, no additional step, direct access.

Comment: Oh damn its so obvious too ! :P